# Memory issue by loading struct-data with fread from binary file and load in a gtk liststore in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gtk

I have a memory issue in my GTK programm and I don't know how to fix it.
The data in the liststore of my programm saved with fwrite in a binary file when I close the programm. The code seems to work:

```
void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *object, gpointer user_data)  
{   
  gint i;
  GtkTreeIter   iter;
  GtkTreeModel *model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(gtk_builder_get_object (builder,"liststore"));
  gint n_rows   = gtk_tree_model_iter_n_children( model, NULL ); //count the rows
  FILE *pfile   = fopen("Data", "wb" );
  gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first (model, &iter);//set iter postion to the first row    
 data *pdata = malloc(sizeof(data));
 for (i = 0 ; i < n_rows; i++)
 {
    gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, 
    SPALTE_ArtName, &pdata->ArtBez,
    SPALTE_ArtNr,   &pdata->ArtNr,
    SPALTE_LBest,   &pdata->LBest,
    -1);
    //just to check the data 
    g_printf("Zeile %d: %s | %d | %d\n",i, pdata->ArtBez, pdata->ArtNr, pdata->LBest);
    fwrite(pdata,sizeof(data),1,pfile);
    gtk_tree_model_iter_next (model, &iter); //iter = next row
 }
 free(pdata);
 fclose(pfile);
 g_printf("Saved successfully!\n\n");

 gtk_main_quit();
}
```

After this when I start the program again it should read the binary file with fread and add the data in the empty liststore
I tried this like this:

```
data *pdata = malloc (sizeof(data));
FILE *pfile = fopen("Data","rb");
if (pfile == NULL)
{
  g_printf("Error: Data File not Found! Creating new list....\n");
}
else
{  
while (fread (pdata,sizeof(data),1,pfile))
{
  g_printf("Test 1 \n\n\n");
  gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter); //add new row
  g_printf("Test 1 \n\n\n");
  gtk_list_store_set (GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter,
                      SPALTE_ArtName,pdata->ArtBez,
                      SPALTE_ArtNr,pdata->ArtNr,
                      SPALTE_LBest,pdata->LBest,
                      -1);
}

free(pdata);
fclose(pfile);
}
```

Here is the data struct used from pdata:

```
 typedef struct _data
{
 gchar *ArtBez;
 gint   *ArtNr;
 gint   *LBest;
}data;
```

The issue must has to do with the pdata->ArtBez because when I tab it out it works fine.
EDIT:
After I red the answer from stark (Thank you so much!) I changed the "data" struct to a struct without Pointers

```
typedef struct _data
{
 gchar ArtBez[128];
 gint   ArtNr;
 gint   LBest;
}data;
```

Then I changed the write function from above to:

```
 void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
gint i, *BufArtNr, *BufLBest;
gchar *BufArtBez;
GtkTreeIter   iter;
GtkTreeModel *model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "liststore")); //Hole liststore aus glade-Datei
gint n_rows     = gtk_tree_model_iter_n_children( model, NULL ); //count rows
FILE *pfile     = fopen("Data", "wb" );
gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first (model, &iter); //Zeiger auf erste Zeile setzen
data *pdata = malloc(sizeof(data)*n_rows);

for (i = 0 ; i < n_rows; i++) //For every row
{
  gtk_tree_model_get (model, &iter, //Get data from row
    SPALTE_ArtNr,   &BufArtNr, 
    SPALTE_ArtBez,  &BufArtBez,
SPALTE_LBest,   &BufLBest,
    -1);
  //Schreibe Daten in Struct
  pdata[i].ArtNr  = BufArtNr;
  strcpy(pdata[i].ArtBez, BufArtBez);
  pdata[i].LBest  = BufLBest;

  fwrite(&pdata[i],sizeof(data),1,pfile); //Write data to file
  gtk_tree_model_iter_next (model, &iter); //Next row
}
free(pdata);free(BufArtBez);
fclose(pfile);      
g_printf("Saved successfully\n\n");
}
```

That works, but when I compile the program, the compiler gets me a warning:

```
 warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   pdata[i].ArtNr  = BufArtNr;
```

Same warning for pdata[i].LBest  = BufLBest;
Where is my mistake?

Comment: You are writing a struct of pointers, not the data that is pointed to.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to fix it? I tried several hours with and without pointers and I have no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

pdata only contains pointers, which are not useful to save and restore. Instead of

```
fwrite(pdata,sizeof(data),1,pfile);
```

you need to do

```
fwrite(pdata->ArtBez,...
fwrite(pdata->ArtNr,...
fwrite(pdata->LBest,...
```

and then build a new structure when you read them back.

Comment: What should I use as size value? Tried fwrite(pdata->ArtNr,sizeof(gint),1,pfile) but get another memory issue

Comment: The gints are not the problem.  Unless the string is a fixed size you will need to write its length, then the string.  On input read the length, then allocate, then read the string.